# Sharing a photo from android app to Flickr - missing caption

Tags: android, android-intent, share, flickr

I'm writing an android application that at some point needs to share a photo with a list of different third party apps including flickr.

I'm using the standard share intent provided in android (code snippet below) and can upload the photo to flickr successfully. BUT the caption that I send along with the photo never makes it to flickr no matter which extra part I add. Can you please advice if there's any other way to send the caption?

More device/OS info: HTC one s/4.1.1/HTC sense version 4+

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentURI);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, caption);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, caption);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, caption);
```

Comment: The Flikr app would need to implement this, do you know that they do?  Bottom line, you can't assume what you are sending is supported (and likely this is the issue)

Comment: That basically was my question! I know that the Intent.EXTRA_STREAM is being used by them since my photo is attached fine to the flickr post. But I guess they ignore all other extras that I'm sending and probably use other extras that are not standard among other social sharing apps. I have already tried "title" and "description" which are mentioned in their other apps, but that didn't work either.